# Update count ID values in one table and display in column of another

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
UPDATE CD
    SET cdNumOfTracks = (
        SELECT COUNT(cdID)
            FROM Track
        WHERE Track.cdID = CD.cdID
        GROUP BY cdID
        );
```

The query above I am using to count the 'cdID' from a table "Track" and have it display this count in the "CD" table as the column 'cdNumOfTracks'. 'cdID' is a foreign key in the "Track" table and comes from the "CD" table. The query works fine but I would have to run this manually to update the data.

I am using this database as part of a website which takes the data through PHP/HTML forms, so therefore I need the SQL backend to update automatically.

For this to be working properly, I would need to be able to add a track, giving it a 'cdID' and this would then add 1 to the 'cdNumOfTracks' column as a new track was added

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is to use a trigger.  You need a trigger (at least) for inserts and deletes, and possibly for updates.  Unless you have a very large database, I would recommend just getting the count directly from `CD`.

I do want to note something.  Because of the `group by`, your query will return `NULL` instead of `0` if there are no matches.  Generally, correlated subqueries do not use `group by`:

```
UPDATE CD
    SET cdNumOfTracks = (SELECT COUNT(cdID)
                         FROM Track
                         WHERE Track.cdID = CD.cdID
                        );
```